# Why is a text not rendering with glow effect but other objects are?

Tags: rendering

I have a project I'm stuck on, it has text and a grid effect (made from a plane) for the floor. I need all objects to have a glare effect emitting light, everything is glowing correctly except one text item, the blue "Media" text. I have added emission the same as the other items and i think done everything correctly in "compositing nodes"[image]

As you can see the pink grid is rendering a glare as is the other texts not shown but the blue "Media" text will not render any glare/emission.
[image]

I've noticed that the other texts and the grid are all showing a "Particles" tab so I've missed something somewhere. That's the only difference i can find between the ones that glare and the Media text. [image]Still really new at this. Spent hours trying to work it out. "Media" text is supposed to be glowing like everything else.Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Update: I think i have narrowed down the problem but have no idea how to fix.
I have a long list of different materials as pictured,the material i;m trying to add to the "MEDIA" text is not giving emission, I've noticed it has a 0 in front of it. So i tried using the other materials and some seemed to work and emit light so i thought great i'll just change to the color i want. However, that doesn't work, when i change the material color at all it stops emitting on rendering.Or if i make a new material for the "MEDIA" text it wont emit i can only add an existing material but not change its color.Would like to use a color i choose, any ideas?
[image]

**Update:**
Blue on text will not emit light in rendering
[image]

All i did here was change color from blue to a different shade or completly different color, kept everything else the same and it would render emission. 
[image]

Comment: Your Text.008 seems to be an actual text object, while Text.005 has been converted to a mesh. It could be that the Transparent BSDF into the Volume Material Output doesn't play well together in this case (perhaps that kills the emission intensity?). Could you try to convert the text to mesh and see what happens?

Comment: Hi, Just tried converting, that didn't seem to work. I have other text items that emit ok and they too are an actual text item not mesh.

Comment: i've removed the Transparent BSDF, still no joy and converted text to mesh, it says CUTEXT.006

Comment: Half year later, but isnt that Glare use to glow according to light intensity, so blue is not bright enough to be calculated for glare? Try to change Treshold value.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this. Glow/glare is determined by a background (it bleeds out past the object). Text and shapes have no background like a transparent image plane would.

Solution: Add a plane behind your thing that won't glow, and make sure to add it to the object/mesh. Make this plan transparent, and it won't render but it WILL provide the background needed to show the glow. It's a coding thing that shouldn't exists.

Comment: I dont think you are right here , on the last two screens you can see there is a background in render view.